# I'm trying to change the colour of the background but it's not working

Tags: c++, opengl, glut

I'm trying to learn opengl with c++ and i'm trying to change the colour of the background. This is the code i've got so far

```
#include <GL/gl.h>
#include <GL/glu.h>
#include <GL/glut.h>

void display();

void init()
{
    glClearColor(1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0);
}

int main(int argc, char**argv)
{
    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_RGB);

    glutInitWindowPosition(200, 100);
    glutInitWindowSize(500, 500);

    glutCreateWindow("Window 1");

    glutDisplayFunc(display);
    init();

    glutMainLoop();
}

void display()
{
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    glLoadIdentity();

    glFlush();
}
```

When I run this I just get a black window with no colour. Can someone tell me what i'm doing wrong

Comment: I have not used glut before, but it looks like the Display func is only used when the window is damaged. Try with glutIdleFunc instead?

Comment: I've tried replacing it but now I get a error because there is no display callback

Comment: Looking at the [GLUT examples](https://www.opengl.org/archives/resources/code/samples/glut_examples/examples/examples.html) it seems you can simply call `glutPostRedisplay()` in your idle func.

Comment: @Botije Do you mean at the end of the init function EDIT: I tried putting it at the end of the init function but it still displays a black window

Comment: Point `glutIdleFunc` to a function that just calls `glutPostRedisplay()`. Point `glutDisplayFunc` at your `display` function.

Comment: @Botje Can you please post a example as a answer EDIT: I tried doing that but now it loads for about 30 seconds and then closes by it self

Comment: The answer I posted works on my machine. Please stop editing your comments, it is very confusing.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <GL/gl.h>
#include <GL/glu.h>
#include <GL/glut.h>

void display();
void idle();

void init()
{
    glClearColor(1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0);
}

int main(int argc, char**argv)
{
    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_RGB);

    glutInitWindowPosition(200, 100);
    glutInitWindowSize(500, 500);

    glutCreateWindow("Window 1");

    glutDisplayFunc(display);
    glutIdleFunc(idle); // added this
    init();

    glutMainLoop();
}

void idle()
{
    glutPostRedisplay(); // tell glut we're overdue for a redraw.
}

void display()
{
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    glLoadIdentity();

    glFlush();
}
```

Comment: I've tried that but now I get this ```Process terminated with status -1073741819 (0 minute(s), 3 second(s))```

Comment: Attach a debugger and see why it crashes, then. This was lifted directly from the "blender" example I linked you to.

Comment: I attached a debugger and it says there's nothing wrong

Comment: No it's still just a plain black window

Comment: Did you do a clean rebuild? I'm starting to suspect you're ignoring compile errors and running with an old build.

Comment: Every time I run it I press build and run because i'm using code blocks and I have just rebuilt it and it still doesn't work

Comment: Try with one of the official [GLUT examples](https://www.opengl.org/archives/resources/code/samples/glut_examples/examples/examples.html) then. If those also do not work perhaps your machine has a problem.

Comment: I was using that and trying to compare my code with the example code and everything is the same except for a couple of values like colour

Comment: I'll try starting again and seeing if that will work

Answer (score 0):

You are not specifying Double Buffer settings (GLUT_DOUBLE or GLUT_SINGLE). By default GLUT_SINGLE is used.

> glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_RGB);

But, there are some drivers that doesn´t allow single buffer window.

I deduce this is what is hapenning. Try to add a glutSwapBuffers() instead glFlush().

```
glutSwapBuffers(); // glFlush
```

Your window is displaying front buffer, but you are clearing back buffer, that never is copied to front buffer.